# Button CSS displaying incorrectly

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to get the style of the 'Add to Cart' and 'Checkout' buttons on this page: http://liff2013.com/product-passes/voodoo-package.html to be the exact same as on this page: http://liff2013.com/workshops.

Not clicked, the buttons are basically the same, however when you click (and hold) the button, the style changes. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well check the CSS properties that get applied …

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the [Chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview). That will make it easy to inspect what styling is actually being applied.

The problem here is you are styling an inner `span` element rather than the button itself in one instance, so when the `:active` pseudo-class is applied you see the inset border kick in. Your best bet if you want both these buttons to look the same is to define a single, re-usable CSS class and apply it to both, with the same HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

The button that looks good :

```
<button onclick="setLocation('http://liff2013.com//checkout/cart/add?product=13&amp;qty=1')" class="addToCart">Add To Cart</button>
```

The button that looks not good :

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
    <span>
        <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

I guess you should check what it looks like without the `span` or with a common class.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the styles you get from `.addToCart` with `.button`, `.btn-cart` and `button`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the same class like this:

Good lookin' button code:

```
<button onclick="setLocation('BLAH')" class="addToCart">
    Add To Cart
</button>
```

Bad lookin' button code:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
<span><span>Add to Cart</span></span>
</button>
```

The fix:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="addToCart " onclick="BLAH">
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The border issue is occuring because you have a CSS property defined for

```
button.button {
    border: 2px outset buttonface !important;
}
```

which is overriding the default inset border when the button is clicked (*:active*).

Other people have already addressed the font issue.